# How to clone a delta table properly? SQL Editor in DataBricks says a column of delta table does not exist but it is

Tags: sql, databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, databricks-sql

I need to clone a delta table from a productive environment to test environment in order to make an analysis. I've tried to use the clonate function but I didn't figured out how to clonate a table based on a sql query. So, my work around was created a SQL query, translate it into a pandas dataframe, after that convert it into a spark data frame and finally insert it into a delta table. I've made it a couple of times for two different tables and it worked, unfortunately in the last one when I querying to see the results after code running, SQL editor shows me next error:

[image]

It's extrange since when I querying a specific column the query editor shows me the data properly and I've tried many times dropping the delta and renaming it but it just does not work, my code is as follow:

```
from databricks import sql
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import os
import pandas as pd

connection = sql.connect(
                        server_hostname = "host_name",
                        http_path = "http_path",
                        access_token = "access_token"
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("SELECT * from schema._production_table")
column_names = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
data = cursor.fetchall()
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column_names)
cursor.close()
connection.close()

column_names = {

    'mandt':'int64',
    'matnr':object,
    'meinh':object,
    'umrez':'int64',
    'umren':object,
    'eannr':object,
    'ean11':object,
    'numtp':object,
    'laeng':object, 
    'breit':object, 
    'hoehe':object, 
    'meabm':object, 
    'volum':object, 
    'voleh':object, 
    'brgew':object, 
    'gewei':object,
    'mesub':object,
    'atinn':'int64',
    'mesrt':'int64',
    'xfhdw':object, 
    'xbeww':object, 
    'kzwso':object, 
    'msehi':object,
    'bflme_marm':object, 
    'gtin_variant':object, 
    'nest_ftr':'int64', 
    'max_stack':'int64', 
    'capause':str,
    'ty2tq':str, 
    '__insert_gmt_ts':'datetime64[ns]',
    '__update_gmt_ts':'datetime64[ns]'
    }

sparkDF = spark.createDataFrame(data.astype(column_names))
sparkDF.write.option('overwriteSchema', 'true').mode('overwrite').format('delta').saveAsTable('schema.test_table')
```

Do you have any options? or could you give me a guide on how to use the clonate function based on a query and not in full table?

Comment: have you tried using `spark.sql("your_query")` which gives you spark dataframe directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clone a full table, then the best way is to use a Deep Clone functionality ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/delta-clone.html), [blog post 1](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2020/09/15/easily-clone-your-delta-lake-for-testing-sharing-and-ml-reproducibility.html), [blog post 2](https://www.databricks.com/blog/2021/04/20/attack-of-the-delta-clones-against-disaster-recovery-availability-complexity.html)) - it will work even if you're repeating it, allowing you to do incremental replication between tables.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE destination_table_name
   DEEP CLONE source_table_name
```

But if you want to insert only a subset of the data, then you can just use `INSERT INTO table SELECT your subquery` ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-dml-insert-into.html#insert-using-a-subquery)). Example from docs:

```sql
INSERT INTO students 
  SELECT name, address FROM persons WHERE name = "Dora Williams";
```

Comment: thanks for sharing, do you know what would be the semantic if I'm making a query from a cursor? I've tried something like this: INSERT INTO bronze.plants_logistics_master_data_mx 
 cursor.execute("SELECT * from brewdat_uc_maz_prod.slv_maz_masterdata_sap_pr0.mx_t001w")